# QgsRasterLayer::identify() is missing after QGis upgrade to 2.0.1

Tags: raster, pyqgis

My Ubuntu has just downloaded the latest version of QGis (1.8 -> 2.01), and my plugin failed with a plenty of bugs due to implemented changes in QGis API.

I still can not figure out how do I replace the function `QgsRasterLayer::identify()` returning the values of the raster layer bands:

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(rlayer_path, rlayer_basebame)  
val = rlayer.identify(QgsPoint(current_point.x, current_point.y))[1]
```

What should I use instead of the one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see now, QGis official site has introduced these changes. The QGis classes hierarchy has become much more complex... So this code worked in my case (getting the value from 1-Band raster by x,y coordinates), but I'm not sure if this way is correct in terms of computational complexity:

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(rlayer_path, rlayer_basebame)     
provider = rlayer.constDataProvider()
qgis_current_point = QgsPoint(current_point.x, current_point.y)
result = provider.identify(qgis_current_point, 1).results()
for key, value in result.items():                          
    print key, value.toPyObject()
```

Note that second argument in provider.identify(qgis_current_point, 1) belongs to enum QgsRaster::IdentifyFormat type.